# VERY strange behavior of sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states in a SQL Job

Tags: permissions, jobs, dmv

How to call DMV **sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states** inside SQL job?

Code is very simple in step:

```
CREATE TABLE #D (DB sysname);
INSERT #D
select database_name
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states;
```

But when job starts, it throws error:
Msg 15562, Sev 16, State 2, Line 3 : The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed. [SQLSTATE 42000]

**WHY??**
Owner of the job - **sa**
Service account of SQL Agent - has role **sysadmin** on the server.

I broke my head. Google didn't help me at all...
Any crazy ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I found medicine:

```
ALTER DATABASE master SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

Thanks to all, guys!